# Reference interpretation in c++

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
void inc1(T&& x)
{
    T y = x;
    ++y;
}

template<typename T>
void inc2(T& x)
{
    T y = x;
    ++y;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    inc1(a); // a is now 11

    int b = 10;
    inc2(b); // b remains 10
}
```

After substitution we have

```
void inc1(int& x)
{
    int& y = x; // reference to x
    ++y; // increments x
}

void inc2(int& x)
{
    int y = x; // copy of x
    ++y; // increments the copie
}
```

In `inc1`, `x` is of type `int&` because both `int&` and `T&&` are references but not both are r-values.

Similarly, in `inc2`, `x` is of type `int&`, because again both `int&` and `T&` are references, but not both are r-values.

My question is about `y`: why in `inc1`, `y` is of type `int&`, while in `inc2`, `y` is of type `int`?

I observed this on both gcc 4.8.1 and microsoft v110 and v120_ctp.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In both function calls, what you pass to the function is an `int &` (in the sense of: "an lvalue of type `int`"). So, presented with the declaration of `inc1`, the compiler must deduce `T` such that `T &&` matches the argument you provided, i.e. `int &`. The only way to do this is to assume that `T` is `int &`, because then `T &&` is `int & &&`, which is equivalent to `int &`. So `T` becomes `int &` and the local `y` is declared as such.

On the other hand, in `inc2`, the compiler must deduce `T` such that `T &` matches the argument type you provided, which is still `int &`. That's easiest done by assuming `T` is simply `int`, so that's what you get for the type of the local `y` then.

---

Reply to a few comments (that have meanwhile been deleted): If you have a function with a predefined argument type, such as

```
inc3(int x) { /*...*/ }
```

then, when you call this e.g. as `inc3(a)`, the compiler will apply whatever implicit conversion necessary *to the argument* to make it fit. In the case of `inc3(a)` this means to transform `a` from `int &` (in the sense of lvalue) to `int` (in the sense of rvalue) – which is called lvalue-to-rvalue conversion and a valid implicit conversion. It basically amounts to transforming the variable `a` into the value it represents at that time.

But when you declare a *template*, such as `inc1` and `inc2` from the question, and the function argument is defined in terms of a template parameter, then the compiler will not, or not only, try to apply implicit conversions to the argument to make it fit. Instead, it will *choose the argument type parameter `T`* so it matches the argument type you provided. The rules for this are complicated, but in the case of a `T &&` type argument declaration, they work as described above. (In the case of a pure `T` argument declaration, an lvalue argument will still undergo lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and `T` will be deduced as `int`, not `int &`.)

This is why, while `int &&` is an rvalue reference, `T &&` (where `T` is a template parameter) is not necessarily an rvalue reference. Instead, it is whatever results from fitting `T` to the argument provided. The expression `T &&` in this case has therefore been called *universal reference* (as oppossed to lvalue or rvalue reference) – it is a reference that becomes either an lvalue or rvalue one, as necessary.

Comment: Why do you say we pass an `int &`? Is this obvious?

Comment: @perreal Yes. The arguments passed are variables declared as `int`: `int a = 10;` and `int b = 10;`, respectively. When such variables are used as arguments to function calls, their type is `int &` (I.e. they are lvalue references).

Comment: To correct my previous comment: The type of these variables is indeed `int &`, so they are _lvalues_ (not lvalue references. That term would only apply to fresh variables declared as references to `a` or `b`).

Comment: You don't pass an `int&`, you pass an `int`! The type of variables is fixed by their declaration and doesn't depend on the context in which you use them. Moreover, you mixed up the _valueness_ of an expression with the _type_ of an expression. The right answer is the one by Tony D.

Comment: @MWid Note that I don't use `int &` to declare a variable. I use it to denote the type (including the "valueness" as you call it) of the expression `a`. Since it is an lvalue expression of type `int`, writing the type of that expression as `int &` makes sense. The Standard does not establish a syntax that can be used to talk about the types/valuenesses of expressions (it uses `int &` only in the context of declarations). But in other contexts (e.g. compiler error messages) it is common to use `int &` to refer to lvalues of type `int`.

Comment: @jogojapan Writing `int &` for an lvalue expression of type `int` is more than confusing. Consider the following: `template<class T> void f(const T&&); int i; f(i);` Following your reasoning, `T`will be deduced to be `int &`. But actually `T` is deduced to be `int` and this code does not compile!

Comment: @jogojapan Given the declaration `int&& a = 1;` how would you denote the _your type_ of the expression `a`? It's an lvalue expression of type `int &&`, so _your type_ is `int && &`?

Comment: @MWid My reasoning did not say anything about the role `const` plays in template argument type deduction.

Answer (score 7):

S14.8.2.1 [temp.deduct.call] says:

> Template argument deduction is done by comparing each function template parameter type (call it P) with
>   the type of the corresponding argument of the call (call it A) as described below.

So, we're trying to work out a P given A of type `int`.

S14.8.2.3 continues:

> If P is a cv-qualified type, the top level cv-qualifiers of P’s type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a
>   reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction. If P is an rvalue reference to a cv-unqualified template parameter and the argument is an lvalue, the type “lvalue reference to A” is used in place of A for type deduction. [ Example:

```
template <class T> int f(T&&);         // <--- YOUR TEMPLATE IS LIKE THIS
template <class T> int g(const T&&);
int i;
int n1 = f(i); // calls f<int&>(int&)  // <--- YOUR CALL IS LIKE THIS
int n2 = f(0); // calls f<int>(int&&)
int n3 = g(i); // error: would call g<int>(const int&&), which
               // would bind an rvalue reference to an lvalue
```

> —end example ]

Your call is just like `f(i)` in the example - which instantiates a function of the form `f<int&>(int&)`... i.e. `T` is `int&`, which is why `T y = x` creates a reference to `x`.

See also Scott Meyers's page at http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers